# Google Play Dev Console showing Class and Method names in Stacktrace

Tags: android, google-play, proguard, android-proguard, deobfuscation

I have an app with Proguard enabled (minifyenabled true) and recently got a crash report in the Google Play Dev Console.  When I looked at it, I saw 
the following:

[image]

I was surprised to see the full class and method names in line 1, as Proguard is enabled. I've always previously seen things like this:

> at com.myname.myapp.c.f (Unknown Source)

I'm also curious how the line number is appearing as I'm not preserving line numbers in my Proguard config file (hence, why I usually see 'Unknown Source' in my stacktraces).

I decompiled my .apk, peeked at the classes.dex file and it all looked OK.  I located the class referenced in line 1 of the stacktrace and the class name was indeed obfuscated, as was the method name.

Now, 'MyActivity' (line 2 of the stacktrace) is the launch Activity of my app, and as such is declared in the Manifest, so I understand why it's name is not obfuscated, and the 'onConnected' method is not a method of mine (it comes from Google Play Games Services), so, again, this is OK.

'MyMethodName' is called from *within* onConnected like so:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    myClassObject.myMethodName();       //Where myClassObject is an instance of MyClassName
}
```

Debug is set to disabled in my build.gradle file.

I don't upload mapping.txt files to the Play Console, I run retrace manually to see my de-obfuscated stacktraces.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me understand why I'm seeing my full class and method name here?  What can/should I do to prevent this?

Comment: Is `MyClassName` is an `Activity` class? Are you using default `ProGuard` rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After weeks of agonising over this, I finally discovered the cause...

Suffice is to say, my released app is completely obfuscated - these de-obfuscated stack traces are coming from **my own test device**!!

Yes, my own test device running the app directly via Android Studio and **unsigned**. (And for obvious reason, I don't enable ProGuard on my debug builds).

The device I used for testing this app isn't a 'mainstream' device and the 'name' that appears in the Dev Consol bears no resemblance to the actual name of the device so I didn't notice straight away.

I'm fairly sure this never happened in the past (I've certainly not see it until now) - quite why anyone would want crash reports from their debug builds to appear in the Dev Console along with production build crashes, I don't know.

So, if someone is seeing this problem, check it's not your own debug builds causing the influx of stack traces before anything else!

Answer (score -2):

> I don't upload mapping.txt files to the Play Console, I run retrace
>   manually to see my de-obfuscated stacktraces.

Then you may want to add the `mapping.txt` to google play which will ensure that your packages and classes names are obfuscated.

Comment: This isn't correct - mappings.txt is uploaded so that you can view de-obfuscated stack traces within the developer console directly without having to manually use a tool like retrace. It has nothing to do with keeping them obfuscated.  Quite the opposite. See: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6295281?hl=en-GB